# Is O_CLOEXEC on open thread-safe?

Tags: file-descriptor

Linux provides many functions to make a file descriptor `close-on-exec` upon creation.

```
int efd = eventfd(0, O_CLOEXEC);
int sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0);
...
```

My question is that: is this mechanism thread-safe? What if one thread forks at the same time another thread calls these functions to create fds? Will I run into file-descriptor leak problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is the whole point of the `CLOEXEC` flag: make it impossible to get this kind of race.  The flag gets passed all the way down to the kernel, so when the fd is created, it already has the CLOEXEC flag set on it.  Here is an example.  Let's say we have two threads.  Thread 1 opens an fd and then sets the `CLOEXEC` flag on it with a separate `fcntl` system call.  Thread 2 forks between the calls to `open` and `fcntl`.  We have an fd leak.

If Thread 1 instead passed `CLOEXEC` into the `open` (or `socket`) call, race is resolved.  If Thread 2 forks before the `open` then there is no fd, and so nothing to leak.  If it forks after, the fd will get closed because it is already marked as `CLOEXEC`.

Comment: Thank you! Greg! Do you know how MAC can achieve this? The `O_CLOEXEC` is particular to Linux. I wonder if OSX has similar function call.

Comment: OSX supports the CLOEXEC flag.